# Re scale Intensity gives dark image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision

I was trying to rescale the intensity of [fundus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvBhS.jpg) image using below code

```
img = plt.imread('ddb1_fundusimages/test/image004.png') # loads in grayscale
alpha = 1 # Contrast control (1.0-3.0)
beta = 0 # Brightness control (0-100)
adjusted2 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)
plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.imshow(adjusted2,'gray')
plt.title("Rescale Image")#, plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,2),plt.imshow(img[:,:,0],'gray')
plt.title("Red Image"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,3),plt.imshow(img[:,:,1],'gray')
plt.title("Blue  channel"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,4),plt.imshow(img[:,:,2],'gray')
plt.title("Green  channel"), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
```

but I got dark image as [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za6Vi.png). Can anyone explain why its happening...?

Comment: try `plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.imshow(adjusted2,'gray').astype(np.float)`, anyway I tried your code, the image wasn't black at all! check your code with the provided image again please! or you can write `plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.imshow(255*adjusted2,'gray')`

Comment: I Checked after 255*adjusted2 some part of the image is visible and is red but according to the equation of convertScaleAbs all part of the image has to be seen...?